# How you should add new information you get as a program goes on to an instance in an immutable language

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I've been having a tough time to get things done in Scala which was easy to do in a mutable world like Java.

I have `List` of instances. (Let's call them `List` of class `Item`, or `List[Item]`) And as the programs goes on, we get more information about each `Item`. (Let's call those classes `ItemAttributeA`, `ItemAttributeB` and etc...) In order not to forget which `ItemAttributeA` corresponds to which `Item`, I'd like to keep them in a same `List` like `List[(Item, ItemAttributeA, ItemAttributeB)]`.

Though this list of tuples already looks pretty ugly, it easily gets much more awful if I have several more case classes. (like `List[(Item, ItemAttributeA, ItemAttributeB, ItemAttributeC, ItemAttributeD, ItemAttributeE, ItemAttributeF, ...)]`

In a mutable world, we could write cleaner code like below.

```
case class Item(id: Int) {
  var attrA: ItemAttributeA = null //
  var attrB: ItemAttributeB = null // fill these fields later
}
val getItemAttributeA: List[Item] => List[ItemAttributeA]
val getItemAttributeB: List[Item] => List[ItemAttributeB]

val items = List(Item(1))
items.zip(getItemAttributeA(items)).foreach { case (item, itemAttrA) =>
  item.attrA = itemAttrA
}
items.zip(getItemAttributeB(items)).foreach { case (item, itemAttrB) =>
  item.attrB = itemAttrB
}
```

Maybe you don't need mutable fields if you use `Option` and `copy`, but it's getting a little messy. And still, it has some problems.

```
case class Item(
  id: Int,
  attrA: Option[ItemAttributeA],
  attrB: Option[ItemAttributeB]
)

val getItemAttributeA: List[Item] => List[ItemAttributeA] // I get list of information at once for a performance reason.
val getItemAttributeB: List[Item] => List[ItemAttributeB]

val items = List(Item(1, None, None))
val itemsWithA = items.zip(getItemAttributeA(items)).map { case (item, itemAttrA) =>
  item.copy(attrA = Some(itemAttrA))
}
val itemsWithAandB = itemsWithA.zip(getItemAttributeB(itemsWithA)).map { case (item, itemAttrB) =>
  item.copy(attrB = Some(itemAttrB))
}

// All item, itemWithAttrA, itemWithAttrB have same type Item. 
// This doesn't sound good because we can't know which instance have the information we want by just looking at the type.
```

My current best solution is using traits that have only one case class as a field.

```
trait HasItem { val item: Item }
trait HasItemAttributeA { val itemAttrA: ItemAttributeA }
trait HasItemAttributeB { val itemAttrB: ItemAttributeB }

val getItemAttributeA: List[HasItem] => List[HasItem with HasItemAttributeA]
val getItemAttributeB: List[HasItem with HasItemAttributeA] => List[HasItem with HasItemAttributeA with HasItemAttributeB]

val hasItem = new HasItem { val item = Item(1) }
val hasItemWithA = getItemWithA(hasItem)
val hasItemWithAandB = getItemAttributeB(hasItemWithA)
```

Well, it doesn't look fancy at all. But at least it satisfies some needs which you couldn't satisfy with tuples. For instance, a case like this.

```
// you want to add ItemAttributeX to each Item in the list.
// but you only need Item and ItemAttributeB to get ItemAttributeX
// you can express that by using type parameters
def getItemAttributeX[I < HasItem with HasItemAttributeB](listI: List[I]): List[I with HasItemAttributeX]

val itemsWithManyAttributes: List[HasItem with HasItemAttributeA with HasItemAttributeB with HasItemAttributeC with HasItemAttributeD with HasItemAttributeE]
val itemsWithManyAttributesAndX = getItemAttributeX(itemsWithManyAttributes)
```

Even though this works somehow, there are so many other problems. (readability, a lot of boilerplates, creating new instances so many times, etc...)

My question is, what is the best way to solve these problems, hopefully in a functional manner?

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case mutability is okay(-ish), but I would recommend to use the classical builder pattern, with a mutable class just for collecting all information. When you collected all informations, you generate the immutable object from that builder (include a test that you really have all information you need). Note that the Scala API itself does it that way (e.g. fill a `ListBuffer`, and create an immutable `List` when you are done). If you want to be fancy, there is even the [type safe builder pattern](http://dcsobral.blogspot.de/2009/09/type-safe-builder-pattern.html).

That said, there are purely functional ways to deal with this kind of situation, e.g. the writer monad. However, Scala is not Haskell, so you can (and should) get comfortable with functional programming in easier situations first before pulling out the big guns.